# How do I handle more than 255 characters in a cell in Excel?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using VBA code to copy paste (`Application.Transpose`) some information from sheet 2 to sheet 1. The code works pretty well, however, I have several cells with more than 255 characters.

I encounter an error with these cells (error 13: type mismatch). I think it dues to the fact that the cell contains more than 255 characters.

Below, the code that I'm using:

```
Sub Bouton3_Cliquer()

Dim O1 As Worksheet 'déclare la variable O1 (Onglet 1)
Dim O2 As Worksheet 'déclare la variable O2 (Onglet 2)
Dim TC As Variant 'déclare la variable TC (Tableau de Cellules)
Dim D As Object 'déclare la variable D (Dictionnaire)
Dim I As Integer 'déclare la variable I (Incrément)
Dim TMP As Variant 'déclare la variable TMP (tableau TeMPoraire)
Dim TL() As Variant 'déclare la variable TL (Tableau de Lignes)
Dim K As Integer 'déclare la variable K (incrément)
Dim PL As Integer 'déclare la variable PL (Première Ligne)
Dim J As Integer 'déclare la variable J (incrément)
Dim L As Byte 'déclare la variable L (incrément)

Set O1 = Sheets("Feuil1") 
Set O2 = Sheets("evaluations") 
TC = O1.Range("B1").CurrentRegion

Set D = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 

For I = 4 To UBound(TC, 1) 
    D(TC(I, 1)) = "" 
Next I 
TMP = D.keys 
TC = O2.Range("A1").CurrentRegion 
For I = 0 To UBound(TMP, 1) 
    Erase TL 'efface le tableau TL
    K = 1 'initialise la variable K

    PL = O1.Columns(2).Find(TMP(I), O1.Range("B3"), xlValues, xlWhole).Row
    For J = 2 To UBound(TC, 1) 
            If TC(J, 1) = TMP(I) Then
            ReDim Preserve TL(1 To UBound(TC, 2) - 1, 1 To K)
            For L = 1 To UBound(TC, 2) - 1 
                TL(L, K) = TC(J, L + 1) 
            Next L 
            K = K + 1 '
        End If 'fin de la condition
    Next J 
            If K > 1 Then O1.Cells(PL, 16).Resize(UBound(TL, 2), UBound(TL, 1)).Value = Application.Transpose(TL)
Next I '

End Sub
```

And the problematic line:

```
If K > 1 Then 
  O1.Cells(PL, 16).Resize(UBound(TL, 2), _
      UBound(TL, 1)).Value = Application.Transpose(TL)
```

Do you have any idea how I can resolve this issue?

Comment: Unless you are using a really old version of Excel, there shouldn't be a 255 character limitation (it's more like 911 last I checked). I suggest you add another loop to transpose the array into a new array item by item.

Comment: I concur with @Rory. A short while back, I wrote a short helper function to redim and transpose an array [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29451126/error13-in-excel-vba-in-data-file).

Comment: I encountered this a long while ago.  If memory serves, VBA was never updated to reflect the change in which cells were no longer limited to 255 characters, so VBA still thinks that is the limit.  I will have to see if I can find the code I was writing at the time to see how I dealt with it

Comment: I agree with @psubsee2003 - VBA will limit you to 255 characters in certain situations. I have a table that can hold up to 300 characters in a cell (entry form limit), but VBA will try to guess what to do with the column based on the first 8 or 16 rows of data. If it's <255, it considers it a string, >255 it considers it a memo. I had to fake the first 16 rows of data with fluff filler to be 300 characters of rubbish to make it work.

Comment: I'm using Excel 2010...
Thank you Jeeped, I will read your short helper.
@Freeman: I tried to fill the first 16 rows with data (more than 300 characters per cell)... and that didn't work.

Comment: I'm still working on my issue. The transpose function is the problem. Ive found that is impossible to use application.transpose with more than 255 characters in a cell.

Do you have a trick to solve my problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Change your monoline statement

```
If K > 1 Then O1.Cells(PL, 16).Resize(UBound(TL, 2), UBound(TL, 1)).Value = Application.Transpose(TL)
```

to this multiline and declare T_TL as variant too

```
If k > 1 Then
    T_TL = Application.Transpose(TL)
    O1.Cells(PL, 16).Resize(UBound(TL, 2), UBound(TL, 1)).Value = T_TL
End If
```

With this you will see if it is the Transpose or the assigning part that doesn't work!

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help.
I tried your solution and it's the transpose line that doesn't work...
T_TL = Application.Transpose(TL).
I have the same error: Error 13:type mismatch