# VBA recursive "For loops" Permutation?

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, recursion, permutation

Below is my code. I would like to achieve the same result by recursive method because the number of nested loops is varying from 2 to max 8.

```
Sub permutation()

c1 = Array(1, 2)
c2 = Array(3, 4)
c3 = Array(5, 6)
c4 = Array(7, 8)
c5 = Array(9, 10)
c6 = Array(11, 12)
c7 = Array(13, 14)
c8 = Array(15, 16)

With Sheets("Criteria")
    .Cells.Clear
    n = 1
    For a = LBound(c1) To UBound(c1)
        For b = LBound(c2) To UBound(c2)
            For c = LBound(c3) To UBound(c3)
                For d = LBound(c4) To UBound(c4)
                    For e = LBound(c5) To UBound(c5)
                         For f = LBound(c6) To UBound(c6)
                             For g = LBound(c7) To UBound(c7)
                                 For h = LBound(c8) To UBound(c8)

                                Cells(n, 1).Value = c1(a)
                                Cells(n, 2).Value = c2(b)
                                Cells(n, 3).Value = c3(c)
                                Cells(n, 4).Value = c4(d)
                                Cells(n, 5).Value = c5(e)
                                Cells(n, 6).Value = c6(f)
                                Cells(n, 7).Value = c7(g)
                                Cells(n, 8).Value = c8(h)
                                n = n + 1

                                Next h
                            Next g
                        Next f
                    Next e
                Next d
            Next c
        Next b
    Next a
End With
End Sub
```

[image: Result]

I have also found a recursive code sample on the internet but i really don't know how to modify according to my need. Any help would be really great.

Recursive code sample

```
Sub RecurseMe(a, v, depth)
    If a > depth Then
        PrintV v
        Exit Sub
    End If
    For x = 1 To 4
        v(a) = x
        a = a + 1
        RecurseMe a, v, depth
        a = a - 1
    Next x
End Sub

Sub PrintV(v)
    For J = 1 To UBound(v): Debug.Print v(J) & " ";: Next J
    Debug.Print
End Sub
Sub test()
    Dim v()
    depth = 4 'adjust
    a = 1
    ReDim v(1 To depth)
    RecurseMe a, v, depth
End Sub
```

Regards

Comment: Can you restate your objective? What do you want to do?

Comment: I would like to set the number of loops as variable. for example in the above example i used 8 loops so output is 2^8=256. but some times i need only 2 for example. so output will be 2x2 matrix.

Comment: it just fills up data from my array. this array length is variable so all loops runs according to each array length.

Comment: If you want to get _full outer join_ of different arrays elements you can take a look at this question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31472816). There are ranges instead of arrays but it's easy to adapt. No need for recursion.

Comment: @BradNicku, Great link! I made an answer on that same post. OP should consider a VBA recordset connection to workbook and run a Cartesian Cross Product SQL across all arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you still want the fix to the code to produce the desired outcome.

```
Sub RecurseMe(a, v, depth, rw)

    If a > depth Then
        rw = rw + 1
        PrintV v, rw
        Exit Sub
    End If
    For x = 1 To 2
        v(a) = x + ((a - 1) * 2)
        a = a + 1
        RecurseMe a, v, depth, rw
        a = a - 1
    Next x
End Sub

Sub PrintV(v, rw)
    For j = 1 To UBound(v)
        ActiveSheet.Cells(rw, j) = v(j) ' & " ";
    Next j
End Sub
Sub test()
    Dim v()
    Dim rw As Long
    rw = 0
    depth = 8 'adjust to adjust the number of columns
    a = 1
    ReDim v(1 To depth)
    RecurseMe a, v, depth, rw
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

For future readers, OP's needs essentially follows a [Cartesian Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product), a mathematical operation of all ordered pairs between sets. One can easily run the [Cross Join SQL](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190690%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) query or specifically a query without any `JOIN` statements to achieve the resultset. This is also known as the full outer join query.

Some SQL engines like SQL Server use the `CROSS JOIN` statement with a resultset equal to rows of product of each included query table (e.g., `2*2*2*2*2*2*2*2 = 2^8 = 256`).

In MS Access (the database sibling to MS Excel), using tables defined as the 8 arrays of two items, below would be the cross join query. Item field in each Array table carries the pairing `(1,2), (3,4), (5,6) ...`

```
SELECT Array1.Item, Array2.Item, Array3.Item, Array4.Item, 
       Array5.Item, Array6.Item, Array7.Item, Array8.Item
FROM Array1, Array2, Array3, Array4, 
     Array5, Array6, Array7, Array8;
```

**Design**

[image: SQL Query]

**Output**

[image: Query Output]

**Excel solution**

Because VBA can connect to various SQL engines by associated drivers including Excel's ODBC Jet Driver, a workbook can connect to ranges of worksheets and run the same cross join query:

```
Sub CrossJoinQuery()

    Dim conn As Object
    Dim rst As Object
    Dim sConn As String, strSQL As String

    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    sConn = "Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};" _
               & "DBQ=C:\Path To\Excel\Workbook.xlsx;"
    conn.Open sConn

    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [ArraySheet1$A1:A3], [ArraySheet2$A1:A3], 
                            [ArraySheet3$A1:A3], [ArraySheet4$A1:A3],
                            [ArraySheet5$A1:A3], [ArraySheet6$A1:A3], 
                            [ArraySheet7$A1:A3], [ArraySheet8$A1:A3]"
    rst.Open strSQL, conn

    Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rst

    rst.Close
    conn.Close

    Set rst = Nothing
    Set conn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: This solution sounds amazingly neat and simple, but can you confirm that `[ArraySheet1$A1:A3]` is **Sheet1!A1:A3**, `[ArraySheet2$A1:A3]` is **Sheet2!A1:A3**. etc? How to modify the `strSQL` to suit different ranges? That is, to build the **strSQL** for generic use?

Comment: Also, can this be on the same workbook as in **C:\Path To\Excel\Workbook.xlsx** connecting to **C:\Path To\Excel\Workbook.xlsx**?

Comment: @Patrick Yes `ArraySheet` is a named worksheet and you can use different ranges in same worksheet. Unfortunately, as far as I know ODBC workbook connections must be done externally and not on same workbook.

Comment: Thanks @Parfait, I will try play around with ranges, hopefully it works for named ranges too!

Answer (score 0):

I approached it as a binary problem:

```
Public Sub Perms(lCyles As Long)

    Dim sBin As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim n As Long

    With Sheets("Criteria")
        .Cells.Clear
        n = 1
        For i = 0 To 2 ^ lCyles - 1
            sBin = WorksheetFunction.Dec2Bin(i)
            sBin = String(lCyles - Len(sBin), "0") & sBin
            For j = 1 To Len(sBin)
                .Cells(n, j) = IIf(Mid(sBin, j, 1) = "1", j * 2, j * 2 - 1)
            Next j
            n = n + 1
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```