# VBA Function where double loop only provides one output

Tags: vba, excel, function, loops

I am new with VBA and trying to do a trinomial option pricing tree with parameters from `-n` to `n` defined. How can I rewrite my VBA function with a double loop to provide all output as it seems to only show the value of `S`. In the end I want to sum all values and discount them but I cannot get past my double loop providing only one output. If I put the MsgBox between `k` and `i` loop it returns nothing. Please can someone assist getting this to work as I don't have the hang of VBA yet.

```
Public Function LoopTest(S As Double, u As Double, n As Integer)

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim k As Integer

    Dim St() As Double
    ReDim St(2 * n + 1)

    For k = 0 To n Step 1
        For i = -k To k Step 1
            St(i, k) = S * u ^ i
            Debug.Print St(i, k)
            MsgBox ("DebugToPrint")
            ' Payoff(i,k) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max((St(i,k) - 20), 0)
        Next i
    Next k

    ' For i from n to 2 step -1
    ' For j from 1 to n - 2
    '     Payoff(i - 1, j) = Payoff(i, j) + Payoff(i, j + 1) + Payoff(i, j + 2)
    ' Next i
    ' Next k

    LoopTest = St()

End Function
```

How do I get output

```
k=0   St = S*u^0 
k=1   St = S*u^-1 , St = S*u^0 , St = S*u^1 
k=2   St = S*u^-2 , St = S*u^-1 , St = S*u^0 , St = S*u^1 , St = S*u^2
```

etc and then sum everything afterwards as output?

Comment: It looks like you're on the right track, but `ReDim St(2 * n + 1)` only gives you a 1 dimensional array. Shouldn't that be something more like `ReDim St(2 * n + 1, n)`?

Comment: Should be `Redim St(-n To n, 0 to n)`

Comment: Thank you so much Chris! This works well. Makes sense now but I didn't really understand ReDim before but this works and makes it clear to me now. I really appreciate this

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally following the example but from the description it sounds like you're interested in a recursive process.  It can be tricky and will leave you in an endless loop if you're not careful.    Does this previous post help you?  [VBA recursive "For loops" Permutation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32873982/vba-recursive-for-loops-permutation)