# Generate a truth table in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, truthtable

I need to make a formula that gives you the truth table for a variable number of columns.

**Example**

[image: sample 4-bit truth table]

Comment: I think [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31472816/expanding-column-cells-for-each-column-cell/31594569#31594569) might be on target for a VBA approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace the FirstCell with a static reference to the cell that contains the first 2^1 value e.g. $D$1 for a 4-bit table (16 values) and autofill to the rest of the grid (in the example A1:D16)

```
=IF(MOD(ROW()-ROW(FirstCell),POWER(2, ((COLUMN() - COLUMN(FirstCell)) * -1) + 1)) >= (POWER(2, ((COLUMN() - COLUMN(FirstCell)) * -1) + 1) / 2),1,0)
```

The logic behind this is:

If the current row modulus 2 power current column (* -1 as the first value is in the last column and + 1 because it starts from 0) is greater or equal to half of 2 power current column, put the value as 1, else put the value as 0.

Comment: Heads-up for those using a regional setting with , as decimal separator => replace occurrences of , with ;

Comment: Really helpful! For everyone else, note that "FirstCell" is the top Right Cell of the table.

Answer (score 7):

The current recommended answer did not work for me. For a simpler method, I'd recommend the following formula:

```
=IF(MOD(FLOOR((ROW()-ROW(TopRight))/(2^(COLUMN(TopRight)-COLUMN())), 1),2)=0,0,1)
```

Where `TopRight` is the top right cell of the truth table.

For instance, if you're creating a truth table with 8 entries that starts in `A3`, replace `TopRight` with `$H$3`, then drag the formula across and down.

---

A basic explanation of what's going on: In truth tables, the rows alternate 1 or 0 every `2 ^ n` number of rows, where `n` is the the number of columns that the given column is away from the rightmost column.

Answer (score 3):

The other answers might make Boole sad.   This one aims to be more boolean.

You need to populate the first row (`2`) with `0`'s

#### For the LSB column (`D`) - Invert:

- `=NOT(D2)*1`  (formula for cell `D3`, copied to `D4:D17`)
- That will invert the value from the row above.  The `*1` numification is necessary to avoid seeing `TRUE` or `FALSE`

[image]

### For all other columns - Add:

- `=XOR(AND(D2:$D2),C2)*1` (formula for cell `C3`, copied to all cells `A3:C17`)
- For an ADD function, you want to XOR the value above in the column with the result of ANDing all the bits in all the columns to the right of it.  (*In other words: if all the bits to the right of the bit above are 1, then you should flip the value from the bit above.  This ADD formula works for any number of columns.*)
- The AND range is referenced to one row up and one col right, to the `$D` LSB column, also one row up.  So the `$D` anchor for the LSB column allows copying to any other column
- Again, `*1` is used for numification of the resulting `TRUE/FALSE`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Microsoft 365 one-liner:

```
=TRANSPOSE(LET(n,5,m,2^n,x,SEQUENCE(n,m,0),y,FLOOR(x/m,1),z,FLOOR((x-y*m)/2^(n-1-y),1),MOD(z,2)))
```

`n` is the number of columns needed, `m` then stores the length of each column.

The formula finds the row of `x` and stores the value in `y`, and then successively halves each row into the correct format, and outputs the result `mod 2` to produce the truth table set of inputs.

`TRANSPOSE` is used because `SEQUENCE` places the numbers left-right, top-bottom.

Answer (score -1):

```
0 0 0 0  
0 0 0 1   
0 0 1 0   
0 0 1 1   
0 1 0 0    
.....
```

remember the numbers are only 0 or 1.

for column D: `D2=1-D1`
  for column C: `C2=IF(D1=1,1-D1,D1)`
    for column B: `B2=IF((C1=1)*(D1=1),1-B1, B1)`
    .....

After did this, copy the numbers without formulas for your truth table to avoid Excel calculation.