# VBA Excel - Generate All Possible Combinations

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel spreadsheet with several calculations. One particular column can be either a "1" or a "2". There are roughly 400 rows in this column.

What I'd like to do is create a method that would create all possible combinations in that column. For example, if I only had 4 rows, I would want to see the following column combinations.

[image: Click to see combinations]

Any feedback or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Flip [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31472816/expanding-column-cells-for-each-column-cell/31594569#31594569) around.

Comment: Not exactly clear on what you are trying to do? Do you want to print the results of "how many permutations with repetition are there if we select 400 elements out of {1, 2}"? Or are the numbers in the original column somehow relevant?