# Column index number

Tags: excel

Can someone help me to be able to use an index number instead of a letter range?

See code below:

```
Function Integer
    Dim value As Integer
```

Comment: I want to say because Columns(2) refers to a Column, not the cells inside the column.

Comment: Hmmm.... Then how to you refer to the cells inside the column? I do have a For Each loop.... But it looks like it doesn't work so well

Comment: Why do you need to use columns? Why can't you just use the range?

Comment: give this a go, I'm not sure if this will work as intended... `Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(1)`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197266.aspx

Comment: Hmm... Nope... Thanks for trying

Comment: If I could remember VBA better then maybe I could help more... But I see no reason why you can't just use a range and have the user insert the range you wish them to check for.

Comment: Just a requirement for a homework assignment. User has to put in a column number into a formula. Kinda ridiculous

Comment: take a look at this... This should help you.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181596/how-to-convert-a-column-number-eg-127-into-an-excel-column-eg-aa

Comment: For starters, see [UDF returns the same value everywhere](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35910683/udf-returns-the-same-value-everywhere/35956748#35956748). You might also want to truncate that column to the intersect with the worksheet's UsedRange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to loop :)

Is this what you want?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim Rng As Range

    Set Rng = Columns(2)

    '~~> This will give you the row number of the max value
    '~~> =MATCH(MAX(B:B),B:B,0)
    MsgBox Evaluate("MATCH(MAX(" & Rng.Address & ")," & Rng.Address & ",0)")

    '~~> OR
    MyVariable = Evaluate("MATCH(MAX(" & Rng.Address & ")," & Rng.Address & ",0)")
    MsgBox MyVariable 
End Sub
```

Comment: This is magical! Although can you help me get it out of the MsgBox please?

Comment: `help me get it out of the MsgBox please` I can't :( My dog ate my magic wand. Have ordered a replacement via ebay

Comment: Oh dang, I really do hate when that happens! The & _ confuse me and I don't really know what to do with them when in a formula :/

Comment: the `& _` is line continuation. One moment updating the post

Comment: Refresh the page. You shouldn't have a problem understanding it now :)