# Moving Active Cell to where your formula is as you copy and paste the formula across a row

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to VBA. I want to use vba function to achieve the following:

Sheet1:

Year ----- |  - 1 -  |  - 2 - | - 3 - |

Revenue  | $10 | $20 | $30 |

Sheet2:

Year ------| 1 | 2 | 3 |

Revenue  | X | Y | Z |

Revenue is a named cell. Using excel function, I can link the revenue of each year to cell X through Z on Sheet 2 or any other worksheet using:

```
=Offset(Revenue,0,column()-1)
```

I want to achieve the same thing in VBA Function to shorten the formula to something like Obtain(Revenue). Here is what I have come up with so far:

In VBA:

```
Function Obtain(Account As Range)
Dim i As Integer
i = ActiveCell.Column - Account.Column
Obtain = Account.Offset(0, i).Value
End Function
```

And in cell X:

```
=Obtain(Revenue)
```

While it does (almost) the same thing as the formula version, I run into problem when I copy the formula from X and paste it to Y and Z across the same row. Instead of getting $10, $20, $30, I get $10, $10, $10 because the Active.Cell is "stuck" to X, unless I move the mouse cursor and press Enter to refresh the ActiveCell for each function in Y and Z. What can I do to this Obtain VBA function so that when I copy and paste Obtain(Revenue) to other cells, excel knows which year of revenue I am referring to?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't use the [ActiveCell property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193314.aspx) in a function. See [UDF returns the same value everywhere](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35910683/udf-returns-the-same-value-everywhere/35956748#35956748) (and others) for more.

Comment: Here is what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559279/excel-cell-from-which-a-function-is-called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to detect cell reference you need to use `Application.Caller`:

```
Function Obtain(Account As Range)
Dim i As Integer
i = Application.Caller.Column - Account.Column
Obtain = Account.Offset(0, i).Value
End Function
```

Comment: I'm not going to down-vote or flag this response but link-only answers are frowned upon and I do not believe you have supplied enough of the related content to let this answer stand on it own. It should have remained a comment.

Comment: Jeeped: Here you go with a proper answer with example. However, If I look at the link you provided in as a duplicate would take me 10 minutes to digest, while looking at the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5559279/excel-cell-from-which-a-function-is-called took only 10 seconds of my life.