# VBA Excel Transform a table

Tags: excel, vba

I am completely new to VBA. I spent half of the day watching tutorials and searching for formulas but it seems that I need to start from at least something.

If you could write a code I would have something to work with and understand the logic of scripting.

The script should check whether the dates in row(7) are within the Start - End dates interval (I think i will manage to put it in user defined variables) and make transformation of the table as per the picture below:

[image: I need to do this]

When the March 2017 numbers are out, I need the script to add the data below of the previously generated table2 (so there should be something like "find the latest row, check if March 2017 is not already there and if not - add data below").

My finance department provides me with the financial statements in the format of the left table, however, in order to the analyze it in BI software, I need to transform it like this.

Comment: Pretty picture. Hire a programmer.

Comment: so this is not as simple as i though
thanks anyway

Comment: It's not hard for an experienced programmer but it would be pointless to provide you with turn-key code that you do not understand. See if you can make your way through a few questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31472816/expanding-column-cells-for-each-column-cell/31594569#31594569) and try to adapt the method(s) for your own purpose. If you run into trouble, come back and show what you have tried and describe what part is not working.

Comment: Stack Overflow discourages full coding gift, although small code set is OK. More to help with a small block of 'how-to'. Look up 'unpivot' in vba for a start. It's simple but then you desire some date constraints. Also the 'unpivot' coding need to be tweaked for you - so you have to start yourself, and then come back to Stack Overflow, or as @Jeeped said, go through a pay-for-code site.

Comment: okay, I got the idea, thank you, guys.
Final question - is there a great place [site] to start from? Or is there some form somewhere where I can input a question and receive the function description and syntax (like the function form in Excel) ? Now I have to google every time. I mastered QlikView in that way from scratch due to it's easy help system but I can't find something similar for Excel VBA. |Thank you.

Comment: @gleba. You should look at `Object Browser` in VB Editor and if you need more explanation than you can check MSDN for documentation and examples.

Comment: Hi there. A number of folks in our community sometimes say that every time they see gendered assumptions about software engineers, they worry about people feeling excluded. I wonder, could you try to avoid adding male-oriented greetings and pronouns in your posts, so as to make for a more welcoming environment? Thank you.