# Google Spreadsheets: generate all combinations of 4 columns with 8 rows each

Tags: function, google-sheets, combinations, permutation

I'd like to create a function for Google Sheets that allows me to list all possible combinations of the numbers 1 to 8, concatenated 4 times (from 1111 to 8888, I think that is 8^4 = 4096).

(I add a screenshot for clarity).

So far I tried with:

```
=ArrayFormula(transpose(split(concatenate(A2:A9&B2:B9&C2:C9&D2:D9& char(9)),char(9))))
```

...but this gives me only 8 combinations: 1111, 2222, 3333, 4444, 5555, 6666, 7777, 8888.

I'm slightly bad at programming, specially with new languages, so any help is very much appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Won't work with [tag:google-spreadsheet] but have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31472816/expanding-column-cells-for-each-column-cell/31594569#31594569).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a little [custom function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions) that creates all combinations of **rows** (it's just easier to write for rows):

```
function combinations(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function(prod, row) {
    var out = [];
    for (i in row) {
      out = out.concat(prod.map(function(x) {
        return x.concat(row[i]);
      }));
    }
    return out;
  }, [[]]);
}
```

Using it as `=combinations(A2:D9)` would create 4^8 combinations, each of length 8, and that is not what you want. But it's easy enough to transpose:

```
=combinations(transpose(A2:D9))
```

The above function returns combinations as a rectangular array, so in your example the output would be 4 columns wide. If you want to join the combinations in one cell (so the output is a single column), use this modified version:

```
function joincombinations(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function(prod, row) {
    var out = [];
    for (i in row) {
      out = out.concat(prod.map(function(x) {
        return x.concat(row[i]);
      }));
    }
    return out;
  }, [[]]).map(function(row) {
    return row.join("");
  });
}
```

Usage: `=joincombinations(transpose(A2:D9))`

Comment: This worked wonders, thanks! It generates the single numbers, as well as all couples and all trios, plus the 4 characters combinations. Which is even better for my purpose, that was to spread all the combinations. For some reason, it also repeats 4 times each result -but this is fine and easy to correct-.

Comment: The repetition was because I put A1:D9 instead of A2:D9, fixed

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
=arrayformula(if(row(A:A)>4096,"",int((row(A:A)-1)/512)+1&mod(int((row(A:A)-1)/64),8)+1&mod(int((row(A:A)-1)/8),8)+1&mod(int((row(A:A)-1)/1),8)+1))
```

(needs at least 4096 rows in the sheet).

Answer (score 0):

### Update May 2023

Sequences can be generated quite effectively with `sequence()`, `filter()` and `regexmatch()`, like this:

```
=let( 
  numbers, sequence(8888 - 1111 + 1, 1, 1111), 
  filter(numbers, not(regexmatch(to_text(numbers), "0|9"))) 
)
```