# Cartesian product for number of sets using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, product, cartesian

Is there a way to create a macro in excel to generate all possible combinations (Cartesian product) of a number of sets (more than 8), each containing a dynamic number of words (up to 60 words).

eg.
if I have 4 sets as below:

- Set 1:    A1
- Set 2:    B1, B2, B3, B4
- Set 3:    C1, C2
- Set 4:    D1, D2

It should create 16 combinations:
[(A1    B1  C1  D1), (A1    B1  C2  D1), (A1    B1  C1  D2), (A1    B1  C2  D2), (A1    B2  C1  D1), (A1    B2  C2  D1), (A1,   B2  C1  D2), (A1    B2  C2  D2), (A1    B3  C1  D1), (A1    B3  C2  D1), (A1    B3  C1  D2), (A1    B3  C2  D2), (A1    B4  C1  D1), (A1    B4  C2  D1), (A1    B4  C1  D2), (A1    B4  C2  D2) -Please see the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MH8I6.png)

The above example is easy to make manyally. But for the below one, it is supposed to create 3456 combinations

- Set 1 A1
- Set 2 B1  B2  B3  B4
- Set 3 C1  C2
- Set 4 D1  D2  D3  D4
- Set 5 E1  E2
- Set 6 F1  F2  F3  F4  F5  F6
- Set 7 G1  G2  G3
- Set 8 H1  H2  H3

Any idea how to do that for dynamic number of sets with dynamic number of words? Thanks A Lot.

Comment: Yes you can create this using VBA. Give it a Try yourself, if it doesn't work then you can post the non-working code here. You can start by learning about `Array` & `loop` in VBA.

Comment: You can find a couple of different solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31472816).

Comment: @mikku
I couldn't really get a firm grip on Arrays, but I understand the loop concept.
So I ended up making it work using just loops. I Tested the macro up to 3456 combinations and compared it to ones I created manually. It worked perfectly. At first the loops were a bit repetitive,  so it took around 3 mins to create the combinations, but then i changed it a bit, it takes less than 5 seconds now.
Thank you for advising me to try it myself ... I have been trying for the last 3 days with no results.

Comment: @BrakNicku Thanks man for the suggested solutions ... am so novice in VBA, I couldn't understand the Array part completely, and how others name their variables.
But as you can see above. I eventually was able to do it just using loops.