# Dumping Excel VBA Array into worksheet not working,

Tags: arrays, excel, worksheet, vba

I've got the following code extract which suppose to dump the content of the array back to the worksheet, but it doesn't seems to work and I'm stuck..could someone please help, thanks.

```
Dim aggressiveDriving(7000) As Variant

For i = 3000 To 7000
    'simple kinematic equation    
    aggressiveDriving(i) = Math.Sqr((((aggressiveDriving(i - 1) / 3.6) ^ 2) + (2 * aggressive_decel))) * 3.6

Next
'at this stage, when I watch the array, it is populated with the expected values in double.
'now writing back to worksheet

With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Current_Driving")
    'if I replace 'aggressiveDriving with '0' then the dumping works with
    'filling 0s
    .Range(.Cells(2, "F"), .Cells(7002, "F")).value = aggressiveDriving
End With
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The orientation of the one-dimensional array is currently 7000 'columns' by 1 'row', not 7000 'rows' by 1 'column' when compared to the worksheet. Use the worksheet's [TRANSPOSE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TRANSPOSE-function-ED039415-ED8A-4A81-93E9-4B6DFAC76027) to reorient it

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Current_Driving")
    'if I replace 'aggressiveDriving with '0' then the dumping works with
    'filling 0s
    .Range(.Cells(2, "F"), .Cells(7002, "F")).value = _
        Application.Transpose(aggressiveDriving)
    'I prefer this method of resizing (+1 because it is currently a zero-based index array)
    '.Range("F2").Resize(UBound(aggressiveDriving) + 1, 1) = _
        Application.Transpose(aggressiveDriving)

End With
```

There are limits to the TRANSPOSE function; typically along the lines of an old XLS worksheet's dimensions.

Comment: Thanks Jeeped, Works like a charm!

Comment: Good to hear. Just be careful with that [TRANSPOSE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TRANSPOSE-function-ED039415-ED8A-4A81-93E9-4B6DFAC76027) function's limits; I think it is a signed int - 1 (e.g. 32,767). See [Error13 in Excel VBA in data file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29451126/error13-in-excel-vba-in-data-file) for a quick home-spun function **my_2D_Transpose** with no limits.

Comment: or just `Dim aggressiveDriving(1 to 7000,1)` and no transpose, because `cells` is a 2D arrays, you also need a 2D array. Logic no? Also, everything from 1 to 3000 will be zeros, and overwritten.

Answer (score 0):

Looping

```
For i = 0 To 7000
'simple kinematic equation    
aggressiveDriving(i) = Math.Sqr((((aggressiveDriving(i - 1) / 3.6) ^ 2) + (2 * aggressive_decel))) * 3.6 
Next
```

start from 0 to 7000, then in equation

```
aggressiveDriving(i) = Math.Sqr((((aggressiveDriving(i - 1) / 3.6) ^ 2) + (2 * aggressive_decel))) * 3.6
```

at i = 0, you will access array in index -1

```
aggressiveDriving(i - 1)
```

Or might be the problem exist in array size.
Array size is 7000,
but you try to write from F2:F7002 => 7001 (size)

Comment: Hey, sorry looping suppose to start from 3000 to 7000 so no problem there..(I've got no problem filling out the array.. )

Comment: Array size is actually 7001 isn't it? because the index starts from 0 right? Anyway, I tried to reduce the range but doesn't help..