# Why am I having issues assigning an array to a Range

Tags: vba, excel

Why is the the first item of my array getting assigned to all cells in the range?

```
Private Sub sample()
    Dim arr() As Double, rng As Range, i As Double
    ReDim arr(1 To 100)
    For i = 1 To 100
        arr(i) = i * Rnd
    Next i

    Set rng = Range("A1:A100")
    rng.Value = arr
End Sub
```

Based on the Locals window, my array has populated as expected:
[image]

But when the array is assigned to the the range, it assigns the first value to all cells:
[image]

Comment: Ranges are 2D arrays, so you need a 2D array : `redim arr (1 to 100,1 to 1) ` for a vertical range

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to assign the array to a range, **the array needs to be declared as a 2 dimensional array.** Even if the 2nd dimension only has 1 element:

```
ReDim arr(1 To 100, 1 To 1)
```

The working example looks like this:

```
Private Sub sample()
    Dim arr() As Double, rng As Range, i As Double
    ReDim arr(1 To 100, 1 To 1)
    For i = 1 To 100
        arr(i, 1) = i * Rnd
    Next i

    Set rng = Range("A1:A100")
    rng.Value = arr
End Sub
```

Comment: No it does not, you just need to transpose the single dimension which is horizontal to a vertical.

Comment: @ScottCraner - until the [TRANSPOSE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TRANSPOSE-function-ED039415-ED8A-4A81-93E9-4B6DFAC76027) chokes on you due to its [antiquated size limitation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29451126/error13-in-excel-vba-in-data-file). It's not a bad thing to start and finish with a 2D array and the transpose's size limitation can be one of those things you never have to think about again.

Comment: ++ Nicely done. However `the array needs to be declared as a 2 dimensional array` No. It doesn't `need` to but like @Jeeped mentioned, if `Transpose` is costing you a lot then one can go with this method too :)

Answer (score 2):

The array is a horizontal 1 dimensional array and it needs to be transposed to a vertical 1 dimensional array:

```
Private Sub sample()
    Dim arr() As Double, rng As Range, i As Double
    ReDim arr(1 To 100)
    For i = 1 To 100
        arr(i) = i * Rnd
    Next i

    Set rng = Range("A1:A100")
    rng.Value = Application.Transpose(arr)
End Sub
```

[image]

The only caveat of this is if there is more than roughly 64,500 elements then the transposing needs to be done manually, with a loop.

Comment: ++ Nicely Explained :)

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
Sub sample()
    Dim arr() As Double, rng As Range, i As Double
    ReDim arr(1 To 100)
        Set rng = Range("A1:A100")
    For i = 1 To 100
        arr(i) = i * Rnd
        rng.Cells(i, 1).Value = arr(i)
    Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: Bad Suggestion. If you want to write to the cells in a loop (Which is a bad idea) then why use an array at all??? `rng.Cells(i, 1).Value = i * Rnd` does the same thing :)