# What is the fastest way to unload a 2 dimensional Array into an excel worksheet using VBA?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, performance

I have a routine that was running long due to a big loop that writes values cell by cell in a worksheet. I thought I would be smart and load everything into a 2D array first then quickly dump it into the excel sheet. Goal being to speed things up. Found out I can't just do what I wanted.

```
  xlsheet.Range("C2") = MASTER_OUT
```

Found out the above doesn't work. MASTER_OUT is a 2D array with 34 cols and various rows. I hope I don't have to loop through the array and place data cell by cell in the worksheet as that won't save any time at all.

Comment: make your range C2 equal tot the ubound 1 and 2 of MASTER_out.  That is make it range(Cells (2,3),cells(ubound(master_out,1),ubound(maseter_out,2))=Master_out.  now my VBA syntax may be a little out of joint, but ubound 1 and 2 of MASTER_OUT should be the number of rows and columns in Master_out

Comment: Yikes I went to school with a Jason Johnson!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[.Resize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa176182%28v=office.11%29.aspx) the destination with the [UBound function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278658.aspx).

```
xlsheet.Range("C2").Resize(UBound(MASTER_OUT, 1), UBound(MASTER_OUT, 2)) = MASTER_OUT
```

**[Addendum:](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TRANSPOSE-function-ED039415-ED8A-4A81-93E9-4B6DFAC76027)**

It is common to flip the rows and columns. If this is the case then use the [Excel Application object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194565.aspx)'s [TRANSPOSE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TRANSPOSE-function-ED039415-ED8A-4A81-93E9-4B6DFAC76027) and flip the ubound ranks.

```
xlsheet.Range("C2").Resize(UBound(MASTER_OUT, 2), UBound(MASTER_OUT, 1)) = _
   Application.Transpose(MASTER_OUT)
```

Please note that [TRANSPOSE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TRANSPOSE-function-ED039415-ED8A-4A81-93E9-4B6DFAC76027) has limitations¹. I believe it starts to become unreliable somewhere around an unsigned integer's maximum value (e.g. 65,536 (...?))

---

¹ See [Error13 in Excel VBA in data file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29451126/error13-in-excel-vba-in-data-file) for a reliable 2D transpose helper function without limitations.

Comment: VBA is not my thing, but is what I said in comments above valid?  I noticed both you and Tim Williams used Resize.  Tim also had a .value on the end

Comment: The default property for a [Range object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx) is the [Range.Value property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195193.aspx) so for all-intents-and-purposes it is never necessary. Call it coding style or whatever but I tend to always use .Value on the source and (almost) never on the destination. Yes, your comment was very valid and would have beaten me by about a half-minute if you had posted as an answer.

Comment: thanks Jeeped. Almost worked perfectly. all the data seems to post in col 3 and row by row what should be col by col. I tried switching the ubound numbers around but that didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: See addendum above regarding transposing (i.e. flipping) the array's values.

Comment: transpose worked. Does this mean when I loaded the array, I loaded it backwards?

Comment: Indeed it does. This is common as most people think in xlA1 terms instead of xlR1C1 terms. If you ever load an array directly from a worksheet's values the 'rows' are the first rank and the 'columns' are the second rank. They are also going to be 1-based, not zero-based like other arrays.

Comment: if I was more sure about my VBA syntax, I would have posted it as an answer.  I knew what the problem was, I knew how to solve it...I just did not know for sure how to write it.