# Is there anyway to write a collection straight into a worksheet?

Tags: vba, excel

Is there anyway to write a collection straight into a worksheet using VBA? something like

```
Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("C2") = MyCollection
```

Can't find anything that works

Comment: Either fill an array from the Collection and then place that on the sheet, or loop over the collection and write the items one-by-one.

Comment: A `Collection`? No. Arrays? [Read this](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx).

Comment: Strictly speaking, a collection like the keys in a dictionary object have to be transposed before dumping back to the worksheet. See [What is the fastest way to unload a 2 dimensional Array into an excel worksheet using VBA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37603174/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-unload-a-2-dimensional-array-into-an-excel-worksheet/37603223#37603223)

Comment: Jake, have you made your mind up to any solution?

Comment: I ended up just setting the collection = an object and using an if statement to write it in. Sorry for my lack of response.

Answer (score 4):

**Edited** to add code for a "Class" approach, as opposed to the "Sub" one already posted

the real closest solution to Jake's answer would be an extension method (possibly named "WriteCollection") for the `Range` class.

Unfortunately VBA doesn't allow for such (and many others, too) a feature, but it can be mimicked to a certain extent with a Class Module approach

---

**"Class" Approach**

1. insert Class Module

   insert a Class Module to your project by clicking "Insert->Class Module" from the main menu

   you'll see a "Class1" sub-node appearing under the "Class Modules" node in the "Project Manager" window
2. rename it

   change its starting name to a meaningful one

   you can do this by clicking the class sub-node in the "Project Manager" window and editing the "(Name)" property value in the "Properties" window (press F4 if you don't already have this window in your VBE)

   let's rename it "MyRange", but you can choose whatever name provided being consistent with it in subsequent steps
3. type in class code

   enter class code pane (double-click the sub-node class in the "Project Manager" window) and add the following code:

`

```
Option Explicit

'---------------------------------------------------------------------
'Properties
'---------------------------------------------------------------------
' all 'Public' properties will be shown by Intellisense for every variable declared of this class

Public Range As Range '<~~ declare a property of the "Range" class. it therefore will have all methods and property of a "Range" object
'---------------------------------------------------------------------


'---------------------------------------------------------------------
'Methods
'---------------------------------------------------------------------
' all 'Public' methods will be shown by Intellisense for every variable declared of this class

Public Sub WriteCollection(myColl As Collection, Optional direction As Variant) '<~~ this will be the method to call and have a Collection written down into a range
    If IsMissing(direction) Then direction = "V"

    If direction = "V" Then
        Range.Resize(myColl.Count).Value = CollToRangeVertical(myColl)
    Else
        Range.Resize(, myColl.Count).Value = CollToRangeHorizontal(myColl)
    End If
End Sub
'---------------------------------------------------------------------


'---------------------------------------------------------------------
'helpers
'---------------------------------------------------------------------
' these are subs/function needed for the inner functioning of the class, so they are declared as 'Private' to prevent their use from outside it

Private Function CollToRangeVertical(myColl As Collection) As Variant
    CollToRangeVertical = Application.Transpose(CollToStrng(myColl))
End Function

Private Function CollToRangeHorizontal(myColl As Collection) As Variant
    CollToRangeHorizontal = CollToStrng(myColl)
End Function

Private Function CollToStrng(myColl As Collection) As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To myColl.Count
        CollToStrng = CollToStrng & CStr(myColl(i)) & "|"
    Next i
    If CollToStrng <> "" Then CollToStrng = Split(Left(CollToStrng, Len(CollToStrng) - 1), "|")
End Function
'---------------------------------------------------------------------
'---------------------------------------------------------------------
```

4. exploit you Class

   add any Module to the same Project your Class resides in and type in the following example

`

```
Option Explicit
Sub main()
    Dim MyCollection As New Collection
    Dim mRange As New MyRange '<~~ declare a variable of the MyRange class and set a new instance of it

' fill Collection
MyCollection.Add "C"
MyCollection.Add "B"
MyCollection.Add "A"

'set the "Range" property of your "mRange" object of the "MyRange" class
Set mRange.Range = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("C2") '<~~ it can be set to any range in any open workbook and worksheet

'exploit "MyRange" class method(s)
mRange.WriteCollection MyCollection '<~~ write down a collection "vertically"
mRange.WriteCollection MyCollection, "H" '<~~ write down a collection "horizontally"

'exploit Excel "Range" class methods through the "Range" property of "MyRange" class object
With mRange.Range
    .Offset(10, 1).Value = .Value & "- offsetted" '<~~ copy/paste values
    .Resize(.Rows.Count, 1).Sort Key1:=.Range("A1") '<~~ sort the collection you just wrote down
End With

End Sub
```

---

**"Sub" approach**

should you need to go on with collection

No, there's no such straight "method" for the `Range` object

whose calling should anyhow be more articulated then the one you wish, since you must at least specify which "direction" to extend collection items from the initial cell

but it should also deal with the actual types of each collection items

just for an exercise I put down a "WriteColl" Sub with the following "signature":

```
WriteColl, Range, Collection [, direction]
```

where direction is an optional parameter to specify the direction where to extend the pasting collection items from given range

and that could therefore be used like follows:

```
WriteColl Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("C2"), MyCollection
```

to do this you must enclose in any module the following code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim MyCollection As New Collection
    MyCollection.Add "A"
    MyCollection.Add "B"
    MyCollection.Add "C"

    WriteColl Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("C2"), MyCollection
    WriteColl Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("D2"), MyCollection, "H"
End Sub

'method
Sub WriteColl(myRng As Range, myColl As Collection, Optional direction As Variant)
    If IsMissing(direction) Then direction = "V"

    If direction = "V" Then
        myRng.Resize(myColl.Count).Value = CollToRangeVertical(myColl)
    Else
        myRng.Resize(, myColl.Count).Value = CollToRangeHorizontal(myColl)
    End If
End Sub

'helpers
Function CollToRangeVertical(myColl As Collection) As Variant
    CollToRangeVertical = Application.Transpose(CollToStrng(myColl))
End Function

Function CollToRangeHorizontal(myColl As Collection) As Variant
    CollToRangeHorizontal = CollToStrng(myColl)
End Function

Function CollToStrng(myColl As Collection) As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To myColl.Count
        CollToStrng = CollToStrng & CStr(myColl(i)) & "|"
    Next i
    If CollToStrng <> "" Then CollToStrng = Split(Left(CollToStrng, Len(CollToStrng) - 1), "|")
End Function
```

Comment: Nicely explained. Good answer.

Comment: @skkakkar thank you. But the real one would be an extension method for the Range class. Which VBA doesn't really allow for, but can be mimicked to a certain extent with a Class Module.

Comment: I shall look forward to it as and when you post it. I have seen some of your posts and feel that you like challenges.

Comment: @skkakkar you're right. I like challenges since I think they are a fine way to try and improve your knowledge. Should I face this, you will be informed!

Comment: @skkakkar: you may want to have a look at the "Class" approach

Comment: @JakeEdwardSandelin: did you get through it?