# Excel Transpose Like Rows

Tags: excel

This should be super simple, and I just can't come up with the keywords to find it, but:

Is there a way to take an Excel sheet that is similar to:

```
a   1
a   2 
a   3
a   4
b   1 
b   2
c   1 
c   2 
c   3
```

and make it

```
a    1   2   3   4
b    1   2
c    1   2   3
```

Comment: look into pivot tables and you should be through

Comment: There are many ways to do this.  Show us what you have tried and where you have hit a roadblock.

Comment: Pivot tables work for sums. I should have specified that the second column values are really 'strings'

Comment: see [Aggregate, Collate and Transpose rows into columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29440349/aggregate-collate-and-transpose-rows-into-columns/29441346#29441346)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am also at beginner level and would like to share with other persons my learning so far. Please use the following code to solve your problem. Please add the Header Row manually as per your requirements.

```
Sub Excel_Transpose_Like_Rows()

Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long, j As Long
Dim colMatch As Variant, colConcat As Variant

Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'disable ScreenUpdating to avoid screen flashes

lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'to get last row

For i = lastRow To 2 Step -1

    If Cells(i, 2) = Cells(i - 1, 2) Then
        Range(Cells(i, 3), Cells(i, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Copy Cells(i - 1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1)
        Rows(i).Delete
    Else
        If Cells(i, 1) = Cells(i - 1, 1) Then
            Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Copy _
                Cells(i - 1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1)
            Rows(i).Delete
        End If
    End If

Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'reenable ScreenUpdating
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, that did exactly what I wanted.