# Grouping a Table based on Text

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, grouping, worksheet-function

I've used subtotals, group by, pivot tables, etc in Excel to sum columns based on an ID. I get tables in the 100's of rows each week with an `ID` column with duplicate values like:

```
table:  
ID  Location
a   Boston
a   NY
c   SF
d   LA
c   Seattle
```

I want to be able to group them without losing data:

```
output: 
ID  Location
a   Boston, NY
c   SF, Seattle
d   LA
```

How would I do this?

**Data Sample #2** **(using @pnuts formulas)** - the problem here is that after deleting the TRUE rows, `banner1` does not show the `1`. It should be `1,2,5` in the `formula1` column in the `banner1` FALSE row:

```
id             cell formula1    formula2
banner1        1    1,          TRUE
banner1        2    2,          TRUE
banner1        5    2, 5        FALSE
banner2        3    3,          TRUE
banner2        6    3, 6        FALSE
banner4        4    4,          TRUE
banner4        7    4, 7        FALSE
```

Comment: Yes. It can be done in Excel.

Comment: @Jeeped edited question. sorry for not being clear.

Comment: I wrote this solution sometime ago. The trick is to walk backwards from bottom to top looking for values above that match the 'group' It should work without modification. If I can find it, I'll post a link.

Comment: Here is something that is close [Aggregate, Collate and Transpose rows into columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29440349/aggregate-collate-and-transpose-rows-into-columns). I've written another that is closer but I'm having trouble locating it.

Comment: I don't know VBA. I'm looking for a formula solution.

Comment: You also can vote to reopen your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an infrequent requirement and assuming `ID` is in A1, this can be achieved by sorting on ColumnA then in C2 entering:

```
=IF(A2=A3,B2&",",IF(A1=A2,C1&" "&B2,B2))
```

and in D2:

```
=RIGHT(C2)=","
```

copying down to suit, copying the results and Paste Special..., Values over the top before filtering on ColumnD to select and delete "TRUE" rows and then deleting Column D.

For frequent use something like VBA may be more practical (possibly created with turning on Record Macro before applying the above process).

Comment: thanks, very close. it works on the sample data posted but I tried it on another sample and see a problem. i posted new data sample in the post.

Comment: thanks, that works great. I have to delete false rows in this case. can you edit the answer? i'll accept.

Comment: ok the sample was generic. your new formula is the better approach. if you update the answer, it'll be easier for future readers. I accepted.