# Unique values and CSV column

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to get the unique values from column A and all the corresponding values from column B in excel. So transform this:

[image: Image 1]

Into that:

[image: Image 2]

Is it possible in Excel?

Comment: [python] or [excel] ? Possible duplicate of [Aggregate, Collate and Transpose rows into columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29440349/aggregate-collate-and-transpose-rows-into-columns)

Comment: In Excel sorry. I already tried the script you suggested, but I can't make it work for my needs unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With data like this in *Sheet1*:

[image]

running this macro:

```
Sub dural()
   Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet
   Dim i As Long, j As Long, st As String
   Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
   Set s2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
   s1.Range("A:A").Copy s2.Range("A1")
   s2.Range("A:A").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo

   For Each r In s2.Range("A:A")
      v = r.Value
      If v = "" Then Exit Sub
         For Each rr In s1.Range("A:A")
            vv = rr.Value
            If vv = "" Then Exit For
            If v = vv Then
               If r.Offset(0, 1).Value = "" Then
                  r.Offset(0, 1).Value = rr.Offset(0, 1).Value
               Else
                  r.Offset(0, 1).Value = r.Offset(0, 1).Value & " ," & rr.Offset(0, 1).Value
               End If
            End If
      Next rr
   Next r
End Sub
```

Will produce this in *Sheet2*:

[image]

*NOTE:*

The data in *Sheet1* is not required to be sorted.

Comment: @Sam  Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim objIds, arrData, i, strId
    Set objIds = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    arrData = Range("A1:B8").Value ' put here your source range
    For i = LBound(arrData, 1) To UBound(arrData, 1)
        If IsEmpty(objIds(arrData(i, 1))) Then
            objIds(arrData(i, 1)) = arrData(i, 2)
        Else
            objIds(arrData(i, 1)) = objIds(arrData(i, 1)) & ", " & arrData(i, 2)
        End If
    Next
    i = 1 ' first row for output
    For Each strId In objIds
        Cells(i, 3) = strId ' first column for output
        Cells(i, 4) = objIds(strId) ' second column for output
        i = i + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This is all you need and nothing must be sorted:

```
Sub Sam()
    Dim c&, i&, d$, s$, v, w
    v = [a1].CurrentRegion.Resize(, 2)
    ReDim w(1 To UBound(v), 1 To 2)
    For i = 1 To UBound(v)
        d = ", "
        If s <> v(i, 1) Then d = "": c = c + 1: s = v(i, 1): w(c, 1) = s
        w(c, 2) = w(c, 2) & d & v(i, 2)
    Next
    [d1:e1].Resize(UBound(w)) = w
End Sub
```

This code is extremely fast. If you were to process a large list, the efficiency here would be appreciated.

You can manage where the source data is and where the output should be written by adjusting the addresses in the square brackets at the top and bottom of the procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at how to solve this using Excel formulae only (I know there is a VBA tag in the OP), but here is another option.

Adding 2 additional columns with formulae we get this result:

[image]

By filtering on the finalList column where the value = 1 we get the desired result:

[image]

The formula that are required are as follows:

Cell C1 :  =B2

Cell C2 (And copied down to all cells in Column C) : =IF(A3=A2,C2&","&B3,B3)

Cell D1 (And copied down to all cells in Column D) : =IF(A2=A3,0,1)

**NOTE:  This will only work when Column A is sorted.**