# How to Split a single cell into multiple rows and add another row

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007, vba

I have a table that has two Columns. Date and Test Name.
What I would like to happen is that the string of text in one single cell be separated into multiple rows. In addition, I need the date to be associated with each set of text. I have tried text to columns and then transpose, but it can only handle 1 set of string at a time and not the entire data set.

[image]

Comment: You will need vba.  SO is not a code for me service.  Also you have two other questions still open with answers.  Did neither answer work for your question?  If they answered the specific question you need to go back and mark them as correct, even if you realized you were asking the wrong question or decided to go a different route.

Comment: Store into array then `split` via space?

Comment: It looks like you need to reverse the code in [Aggregate, Collate and Transpose rows into columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29440349/aggregate-collate-and-transpose-rows-into-columns).

Comment: @Jeeped - holy cow, thanks for that link/question.

Comment: @ScottCraner Thank you Scott, I thought I had marked them correct, but I guess I did not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Loop through Column A then loop through the string next to it.

### Results will be in column D

```
    Sub ChickatAH()
    Dim rng As Range, Lstrw As Long, c As Range
    Dim SpltRng As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Orig As Variant
    Dim txt As String

    Lstrw = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = Range("A2:A" & Lstrw)

    For Each c In rng.Cells
        Set SpltRng = c.Offset(, 1)
        txt = SpltRng.Value
        Orig = Split(txt, " ")

        For i = 0 To UBound(Orig)
            Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Offset(1) = c
            Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Offset(, 1) = Orig(i)
        Next i

    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: This was exactly what i was looking for. I was only able to split the string for 1 range, but I couldn't figure out how to get it to match with the date. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: If i wanted to pull out more data correlating to Date and Test prior to split ( so if after test1 test 2 test3 in column c there is HIstory exam) and have that data be shown with date and test, would I just add a counter or a for loop?

Comment: I think I know what you mean, since this thread has already been answered, you can start a new thread with the new question.

Answer (score 2):

This will require a bit of copy and paste and also the use of WORD but here are a few steps that should help you out.

1. Copy the cell in question.

   Open Word

   Paste Special (use the dropdown arrow below the paste icon)

   Select the option - Unformatted Unicode Text (as your paste special option)

   Select All

   Replace

   Find What:  (type in the space) Replace With: ^p (creates a new line)

   Copy and paste results back into excel

Comment: Doing this in vba would be much faster.  The code would only be 10-15 lines long.

Comment: Just an FYI, it was not I that voted it down.  I can see your point.

Answer (score 0):

A formula solution is close to your requirement.

[image: Image shown here.]

Cell `H1` is the delimiter. In this case a space.

```
Helper E1:=SUM(E1,LEN(B1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B1,$H$1,"")))+1
```

You must fill the above formula one row more.

```
A8:=a1
```

Fill this formula to the right.

```
A9:=LOOKUP(ROW(1:1),$E:$E,A:A)
```

Fill this formula to the right and then down.

```
B9:=MID($H$1&LOOKUP(ROW(A1),E:E,B:B)&$H$1,FIND("艹",SUBSTITUTE($H$1&LOOKUP(ROW(A1),E:E,B:B)&$H$1,$H$1,"艹",ROW(A2)-LOOKUP(ROW(A1),E:E)))+1,FIND("艹",SUBSTITUTE($H$1&LOOKUP(ROW(A1),E:E,B:B)&$H$1,$H$1,"艹",ROW(A2)-LOOKUP(ROW(A1),E:E)+1))-FIND("艹",SUBSTITUTE($H$1&LOOKUP(ROW(A1),E:E,B:B)&$H$1,$H$1,"艹",ROW(A2)-LOOKUP(ROW(A1),E:E)))-1)
```

Fill down.

Bug:

Date/time will be converted to value and blank will be filled with 0. You can add &"" to the end of the formula of `A9` and `B9` to block the value 0, but numbers/date/time will be converted to text.